# jQuery - Changing the text property of a class

Tags: jquery, html, class, text, selector

How do I change the `text` of a `class` using `jQuery`?

Here is the `html` code:

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box box-default">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Collapsable</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
      </div><!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body" id="testBody">
        The body of the box
      </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>      

<div class="box2">
    <div class="box box-default">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Collapsable</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
      </div><!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body" id="testBody">
        The body of the box
      </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

How can I change the `box1` and `box2` `box-title` `class` `text` to a different value?

I am referring to this line of html code for each box:

```
<h3 class="box-title">Collapsable</h3>
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
$('.box1.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title').text("Box 1 title");
$('.box2.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title').text("Box 2 title");
```

The text is not changing, and no errors are being shown in the console.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .box1.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title

is an incorrect selector. Simply do

```
$('.box1 .box-title').text("Box 1 title");
```

The selector is saying -> container `.box1` containing a direct or nested `.box-title`

```js
$('.box1 .box-title').text("Box 1 title");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box box-default">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Collapsable</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
      </div><!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body" id="testBody">
        The body of the box
      </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>      

<div class="box2">
    <div class="box box-default">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Collapsable</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
      </div><!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body" id="testBody">
        The body of the box
      </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('.box1.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title').text("Box 1 title");
$('.box2.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title').text("Box 2 title");
```

To this:

```
$('.box1.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title').html("Box 1 title");
$('.box2.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title').html("Box 2 title");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
$('.box-title').val("Box 1 title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code...

## Wrong Selector

Looking at your HTML ,`box-header` also has class `with-border`. But your selector passed in jQuery tells a different story.

```
$('.box1.box box-default.box-header with-border.box-title')
```

...would actually be

```
$('.box1 .box.box-default .box-header.with-border .box-title')
```

Elements with multiple classes together come together as CSS selectors. Including a space in between means the one on right is a `descendant` of the one on the left.

## Too Many Selectors

While this does not prevent you from getting desired result, it's always a good practice to use less specific CSS selectors. What you are looking for could easily be done by doing the following.

```
$(".box1 .box-title").text("Box 1 Title");
$(".box2 .box-title").text("Box 2 Title");
```